# Vue Router horizontal scroll to hash not working

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I want to use a `button` wrapped into `router-link` to scroll the viewport horizontally (`100% to the right` to a `vue component`. This works fine with `anchor tags`:

```html
<a href="#about">
    <button class="btn">About</button>
</a>
```

but as soon as I try to replace them with `router-link` the horizontal scroll stops working (vertical scroll still works):

```html
<router-link :to="{ hash: 'about' }">
    <button class="btn">About</button>
</router-link>
```

This function inside `router.js` is responsible for the scroll:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import VueRouter from "vue-router";

Vue.use(VueRouter);

export default new VueRouter({
    mode: "history",
    routes: [...],
    scrollBehavior(to, from, savedPosition) {
        if (to.hash) {
            return window.scrollTo({top: document.querySelector(to.hash).offsetTop, behavior: 'smooth'});
        }
        return window.scrollTo({top: 0, behavior: 'smooth'});
    }
});
```

The component to which the viewport is to be scrolled has been placed on the right side outside the viewport like so:

```
.about {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(100%);
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}
```

**Edit:**

Changing the button to:

```
<button @click="$router.push({ hash: 'about' })">About</button>
```

makes the viewport scroll down about `20%` and only vertical , not horizontal. I don't know why this behaviour occurs. `scrollBehavior(to, from, savedPosition) {console.log(to)}` shows this:

```
{name: 'home', meta: {…}, path: '/', hash: '#about', query: {…}, …}
fullPath: "/#about"
hash: "#about"
matched: [{…}]
meta: {}
name: "home"
params: {}
path: "/"
query: {}
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

Comment: `document.querySelector('#'+to.hash)` isn't it ?

Comment: @FatimaMazhit if I make this change I am getting errors thrown and the scroll stops working

Comment: I am just pointing that you are missing id selector. You are searching only for tag with name 'about' but you actually should search like `document.getElementById(to.hash)`

Comment: If I do that I am getting `Error in nextTick: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of null`

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
<button @click="$router.push({ hash: 'about' })">About</button>
```

Comment: I tried doing that. Please take a look at the `Edit Section`.